# Каким плагином для gulp конвертировать шрифты в woff

Tags: gulp, шрифты

У меня сборка на gulp. Сейчас я кодирую подключаемые шрифты в base64 при помощи [gulp-font2css](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-font2css/). Он нормально подключает `OTF`, `TTF`, `WOFF` и прочие. Но мне хотелось бы дополнительно все шрифты конвертировать в `WOFF`, чтобы выиграть лишние килобайты.

Кроме того не хотелось бы каких-либо глобальных зависимостей. Я пробовал поставить [gulp-fontgen](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-fontgen/), но он начал меня просить поставить `fontfroge` и я дальше не стал разбираться. Хотя если не найдется другого варианта, то я буду работать с ним. Если он вообще работает.

Всё остальное странице плагинов `GulpJS` либо просто кодирует шрифты в `base64`, как `gul-font2css`, либо подключает шрифты из `Google Fonts`, а это не мой случай. Еще я видел [gulp-ttf2woff](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ttf2woff), но он только с `TTF` работает, поэтому не то. Ну и мне показалось, что его `gulp-fontgen` подключал, как зависимость, а, значит, там тоже может быть нужен `fontfroge`. Хотя я не проверял.

Ну и третье, чего бы хотелось, это иметь возможность выпиливать глифы, как это умеет делать `Font Squirrel`, но это уже программа-максимум.

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/company/adv/blog/184864/ - пункт 9

Comment: Самый лучший совет, который можно дать — это отказаться от конвертирования шрифтов в base64, потому что так вы получаете целую кучу килобайт в блокирующий рендер CSS.

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko я их буду кэшировать в localStorage.

Comment: @Qwertiy я знаю об этом. Тем не менее очень часто шрифт можно конвертировать без заметных проблем

Comment: @shugich если собираетесь кешировать шрифт, то почему бы тогда не кешировать шрифт в обычном формате? заодно до загрузки шрифта можно фоллбек показывать.

Comment: Потому что мне проще кэшировать один файл с закодированном шрифтом, а не несколько файлов шрифтов и файл с css.

Comment: @shugich про fontfaceobserver слышали?

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko, это штука, которая помогает определить загружен ли шрифт? Но как она может мне помочь? У меня ведь нет проблемы с проверкой на загрузку.

Comment: это штука, которая контролирует загрузку шрифта и поддерживает запись в sessionStorage. https://elliotekj.com/2017/01/11/improving-webfont-performance-with-fontfaceobserver-and-sessionstorage/

Comment: Так, а я записываю в localStorage и так же контролирую подргрузку шрифта. Но проблема в том, что мне нужен WOFF, а не TTF/OTF, чтобы первая загрузка шрифта проходила быстрее и расходовалось меньше места в localStorage.

Answer (score 1):

Для конвертации в WOFF можно использовать gulp-fonter
(в WOFF2 не конвертирует)

```js
npm i - D gulp - fonter

const fonter = require('gulp-fonter');

gulp.task('fonts', () => {
  return gulp
    .src('./src/fonts/*')
    .pipe(fonter({
      subset: [66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71],
      formats: ['woff', 'ttf']
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-fonter